# Filtering rows in dataframe based on partial column name and mathematical expression

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to filter rows using both the partial name of the column headers and a mathematical expression (x > 0). Given my data here:

```
    OTU_ID       X3_22L15_S   X3_22T10_W   X3_22L6_S   X3_22Algae 
1   denovo109       16            0            9            0
2   denovo147       44          484           28            0
3   denovo297        0            0            7           14
4   denovo1013       0            1            0            0
```

I want to include only the rows that have a value > 0 in columns with headers that end in "S" AND columns that end in "W". I've found ways to filter the columns based on a substring of column headers and ways to filter based on values in a certain column, but have not found anything that allows me to filter based on values > 0 that occur simultaneously in two sets of columns specified by different substrings.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to keep column ends with "W" no matter what the values in row are?

Comment: Yes. I only need the rows that have a value > 0 in any column ending in W & any column ending in S.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer by replacing `all_vars` to `any_vars`. Please let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: After seeing Jaap's answer, I think separated `filter_at` call probably is the best way to filter the data. I further updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
cols <- grep('[SW]$', names(df), value = TRUE)
df[rowSums(df[, cols] > 0) == length(cols),]
```

gives:

> ```
>      OTU_ID X3_22L15_S X3_22T10_W X3_22L6_S X3_22Algae
> 2 denovo147         44        484        28          0
> ```

This assumes that you only want to keep the rows that have all values above zero for the columns ending on `S` or `W`.

NOTE: `value = TRUE` can be omitted in `grep`, which will then give a numeric vector back

---

In respons to your comment, if want to treat the columns ending on `W` separate from the columns ending on `S` you could do:

```
wcols <- grep('W$', names(df), value = TRUE)
scols <- grep('S$', names(df), value = TRUE)

df[rowSums(df[, wcols, drop = FALSE] > 0) & rowSums(df[, scols, drop = FALSE] > 0),]
```

which gives:

> ```
>      OTU_ID X3_22L15_S X3_22T10_W X3_22L6_S X3_22Algae
> 2 denovo147         44        484        28          0
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This does work for rows that have values > 0 for all columns ending in W and all columns ending in S, but I realized I should have been more specific.

Is there a way to keep the rows that have a value > 0 in any column ending in W & any column ending in S?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `filter_at` from the `dplyr` package. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "    OTU_ID       X3_22L15_S   X3_22T10_W   X3_22L6_S   X3_22Algae 
1   denovo109       16            0            9            0
                 2   denovo147       44          484           28            0
                 3   denovo297        0            0            7           14
                 4   denovo1013       0            1            0            0",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Filter the data, with any column ends with "S" or "W" and values > 0
dt2 <- dt %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("S")), any_vars(. > 0)) %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("W")), any_vars(. > 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `grep` can be used. This is one approach:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "    OTU_ID       X3_22L15_S   X3_22T10_W   X3_22L6_S   X3_22Algae 
1   denovo109       16            0            9            0
                 2   denovo147       44          484           28            0
                 3   denovo297        0            0            7           14
                 4   denovo1013       0            1            0            0",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Filter the data, with any column ends with "S" or "W" and values > 0
df2 <- dt[,grep(pattern="^Algae",colnames(dt)]


dt2 <- dt %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("W")), any_vars(. > 0))


df2 <- data.frame(dt[,grep(pattern="Algae",colnames(dt))])


dt <- dt %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("S")), any_vars(. > 0)) %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("W")), any_vars(. > 0))  

dt2 <- data.frame(dt[,-grep(pattern="Algae",colnames(dt))])
```

On executing `dt2`, one gets this output:

```
> dt2
     OTU_ID X3_22L15_S X3_22T10_W X3_22L6_S
1 denovo147         44        484        28
```